# Does this sequence converge $a_n=\frac {3^{n+2}}{5^n} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does this sequence converge $$a_n=\frac {3^{n+2}}{5^n} ?$$
I'm trying to determine if my approach works. What I did was remove the constant $3^2$ this would give me:

$$9 \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {3^n}{5^n} $$
I figure I can divide the top $n$ exponent by the bottom and remove them. giving me:

$$9 \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {3}{5} $$

which should make it converge to $\frac {27}{5}$ But for some reason I think this process is wrong. I would love someone to show me if this is the correct process to this problem.

Comment: Could you please develop your approach a little more?

Comment: Is this a sequence or a series?  Are you finding $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$, or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$?

Comment: In general you cannot divide exponents in the manner you are suggesting.

Comment: Note: $\frac{3^n}{5^n}=(\frac{3}{5})^n$, which is not the same as $\frac{3}{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

You started well but got lost along the way:
$$
\frac {3^{n+2}}{5^n} = 9 \frac {3^n}{5^n} = 9\left(\frac {3}{5}\right)^n
\to 0
$$
because $0 < 3/5 <1$.

Comment: I would add the bound $-1<3/5$.

Comment: is this the sequence rule of $r^n$?

Answer (score 0):

the sequence $b_n=\frac{3^n}{5^n}$ tends to zero and the sequence $c_n=9$ tends to 9 and $a_n = b_n \cdot c_n$ will tends to multiplication of zero and 9.